# 7 Adar, Tachanun and Leap Years

Tags: minhag, moshe-rabbeinu, tachanun, yahrtzeit, leap-years

A followup to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55742/tachanun-on-7-adar) question.

For those who do not say [tachanun](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89705/zayin-adar-customs) on the birth/death [anniversary](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55816/how-do-we-know-that-moshe-rabbeinus-yahrtzeit-was-7-adar) of Moshe Rabbeinu, how do they handle leap years? Do they not say tachanun on the seventh of both months Adar? Only the first? The second?

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68102/what-is-the-halacha-regarding-adar-yahrtzeits) question mentions the opinions about the general rule of Yahrzeits in the 2 Adars in a leap year but I don't know if these opinions are applied to what amounts to one opinion about the actual date and whether the month was a leap year or not -- for other views, see [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/zayin-adar/#ftnref1).

Note -- this is not even Purim Koton Torah in Lesser Jest

Comment: Do we even have a PKTILJ policy here? If we don’t we should.

Comment: I think one should follow the same halacha for Moshe Rabbeinu as he would do for his own relative's yahrtzeit. Why should Moshe receive any lesser treatment than a relative, when he was a more important person?

Comment: Is it possible to work out if he died in a leap year?

Comment: @DanielRoss Probably not. Prior to the fixed calendar, Sanhedrin, and before Sanhedrin it was probably the judges and "elders" who would declare a leap year when needed; sometimes "suddenly". I.e., assuring that Pesach begins after the Spring Equinox is just one factor. Other factors included road conditions for the pilgrimage, the ripening of the barley by 16 Nisan and some other factors. Of course, in the desert, the equinox issue was probably the only concern. But, any calculations someone would do would be based on assumptions of our current 19-year cycle, which didn't exist then!