# Moshe's exact month of birth

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu

In a recent shiur, the Rav said that Moshe told Yehoshua to pick men to fight Amalek.  The reason appears in the following passage:

למה ליהושע, כדי שיבחר אנשים שנולדו באדר שני כמותו

On the source sheet, it says that this פרוש comes from the Midrash Torah Shleimah, which I've never heard of before.

Was Moshe A'H really born in Adar Sheni?  I always thought that Moshe was born in Adar Rishon and niftar in Adar Sheni.  Please clarify.

Comment: Torah Sheleima is by R Menachem Mendel Kasher. He quotes various midrashim.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3717/moshe-rabeinus-yarzheit?r=SearchResults

Comment: I beleive this is a misread of the Midrash. כמותו means like Yehoshua, not like Moshe.

Answer (score 1):

This comes from Midrash VeHizhir [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38577&st=&pgnum=83) (num. 3).

(What was given in the source sheet might’ve/should’ve been “מדרש, תורה שלמה” = ‘[a] Midrash’ cited in ‘Torah Shelemah’ by [R. Kasher](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_Kasher).)

Answer (score 0):

Let me start my Answer by explaining that It's not possible  Moshe could have been born on 'אדר א and be niftar on 'אדר ב, for two simple reasons #1. Moshe Rabbinu was niftar at 120 years old. #2 He lived a complete (full) number of years. (Meaning he passed away after a full 120 years to the day of his birth (on ז' אדר). If Moshe passed on 'אדר ב that would be an un- full 121 years.

Perhaps what you always thought,  (And some Midrashim do in fact say-  (it's a Machlos)  was that Moshe was born on a Regular ז  אדר  and he was niftar on a "Leap Year" with an אדר ב, and he passed on 'ז' אדר ב. That's considered "A Full 120 years" (As the  שולחן עורך brings down the Halacha by a Bar Mitzva. A kid born Reg. Adar who turns 13 on a Leap Year becomes a Bar Mitzvah on the 2nd Adar. Interestingly, this case works the opposite way as well.)

Now, the bottom line is that it's an Argument when Moshe died.The Pasuk.  in V'Zot HaBerachah at Moshe's passing says: וַיִּבְכּוּ֩ בְנֵ֨י יִשְׂרָאֵ֧ל אֶת־מֹשֶׁ֛ה בְּעַֽרְבֹ֥ת מוֹאָ֖ב שְׁלֹשִׁ֣ים י֑וֹם וַֽיִּתְּמ֔וּ יְמֵ֥י בְכִ֖י אֵ֥בֶל מֹשֶֽׁה׃

Some Midrasim explain: After his death that Beni Yisrael mourned for Moshe Rabbinu for 30 days,  and then had Hespedim for him for another 30 days, totalling 60 days in which case Moshe passed on  a Leap Year on אדר ב.    Other Midrashem hold they Mourned for 30 days ( Hespid included in that time), and he passed on  a Regular אדר.

Now, According to this Midrash VeHizhir that "Oliver" brought and "Double AA" found out was brought down by Rabbi M. Kasher who wrote a "Likud" (gathering) of various Midrashim, in his Sefer titled Torah Sheleima, that your Rav told you about, were it says that Moshe picked Yehoshua to help him lift his hands so Beni Yisrael will be victorious over Amalek, because they were both born on אדר ב, then the Midrash VeHizhir can hold either way.      Either that Moshe died on a Regular ז אדר  or on a "עיבור שנה" (Leap Year) on 'ז' אדר ב.

Hope I helped. Good Shabbos.
P.S. If you- Or anyone elese on this Page want to understand the Machlos in detail, with a reconciliation I  added this Link to the Chasam Sofer.(https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.34.8?with=Chatam%20Sofer)

Comment: Thank you, Sochacz, for your comprehensive answer.  Is there any other evidence that Yehoshua was indeed born in Adar Sheni, or can we just infer it from this Midrash? Shabbat Shalom.